# Python lxml parse XML with XSD schema validation error Mac OS Sierra

Tags: python, macos, lxml, libxml2, macos-sierra

There is a problem. I have such code for validating generated XML before:

```
    tree = self.get_tree()
    res = etree.tostring(tree, xml_declaration=True, encoding='windows-1251', pretty_print=True)
    with open(self.SCHEMA_PATH) as xsdfile:
        schema = etree.XML(xsdfile.read())
    parser = etree.XMLParser(schema=etree.XMLSchema(schema))
    etree.fromstring(res, parser)
```

This code is working in Mac OS Yosemite, but after upgrade to Sierra, I have a problem with validation XML attributes. It says that attribute length is '0', but printing `res` says that attribute has value.
I've tried to reinstall homebrew, libxml2, and python lxml. xcode was updated before Sierra upgrade, so looks like it has last version. Nothing helps me...

Any idea What is happening.

Comment: Looks like that problem in XSD Schema parser, because I can get valid xml by 'fromstring' without specifying parser.

Comment: I have the same problem after updating to Sierra

Comment: I don't think is the OS - I think this is lxml - Can you run `xmllint --noout --schema <file.xsd> <file.xml>`